# I can't check for updates

Tags: 11.10, package-management, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

After I installed some updates I restarted my computer.

Some days later I wanted to check for updates because the "update-manager" shows me the following: "The packet information has been updated last 24 days ago."  and a window appeared.

That window after downloading packages, said that:

> Failed to download the information from the repository
>
> Check your Internet connection
>
> Details:
>
> W:GPG error: **http://ppa.launchpad.net** oneiric Release: The following
>   signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
>   available: NO_PUBKEY 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0, W:Failed to fetch
>   **http://ppa.launchpad.net/jsevi83/unity/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources**
>   404  Not Found , W:Failed to fetch
>   **http://ppa.launchpad.net/jsevi83/unity/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages**
>   404  Not Found , W:Failed to fetch
>   gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ar.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_universe_i18n_Translation-en
>   Encountered a section with no Package: header , E:Some index files
>   failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

But my Internet connection works fine.

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the error with signature:

```
sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0
sudo gpg --armor --export 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and post output if errors do occurr.

Comment: edited, try again please!

Comment: The reason you need to do this is that you added a PPA to your `sources.list` without trusting the key it uses to sign packages.

Comment: Doesn't work why? Please, post your output!!!

Comment: As you can see, signature error is not appearing.
Those other ones are because you're using unupdated repos. You'd better disable them.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: I solved the problem deleting the outdated repositories.